# Replace Some Columns of DataFrame with Another (Based on Column Names)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df1`:

```
| A | B | C | D |
-----------------
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
```

and a `DataFrame` `df2`:

```
| A | D |
---------
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 9 |
```

I want to replace column `A` and `D` of `df1` with the equivalent columns of `df2`.

Surely I could do something like

```
df1['A'] = df2['A']
df1['D'] = df2['D']
```

But I need a solution for doing this automatically since I have thousands of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is with [**`pd.DataFrame.update`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)
Update will modify a dataframe in place with information in another dataframe.

```
df1.update(df2)
```

The advantage of this is that your `dtypes` in `df1` are preserved.

```
df1

   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  3  2
1  3  1  8  2
2  1  2  3  9
```

---

Another way to have done this with out updating in place would be to have used [**`pd.DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and dictionary unpacking on [**`pd.DataFrame.iteritems`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html).  However, this would include new additional columns if they existed in `df2`.

```
df1.assign(**dict(df2.iteritems()))

   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  3  2
1  3  1  8  2
2  1  2  3  9
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2.combine_first(df1)

#   A   B   C   D
#0  2   1.0 3.0 2
#1  3   1.0 8.0 2
#2  1   2.0 3.0 9
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple for loop should suffice:

```
for c in df2.columns:
    df1[c] = df2[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df1.columns:
    if col in df2.columns.tolist():
        df1[col] = df2[col]
```